# How to setup java web architecture on hosting slice/dedicated server?

Tags: java

I want to build web application that is based on java technology (tomcat ) 
Can I get please suggestions on how to set up the servers (apache – mod_jk – tomcat ? ) 
And what are the right frameworks to use or not .
For memory and ease of work from the development side ( to use plain jsp or mvc frame works? )

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't ask for alternatives to tomcat, if you are starting to look into web development you should have a look at [Caucho's Resin](http://www.caucho.com/download/). I find it is a better alternative than tomcat and makes it very easy to setup a system for test and development. It is completely built in Java and the open source version is free.

Comment: well i feel very conferrable with java, but i know its memory eater compared to php. but maybe i wrong and today java web is much better i dont know  i didnt do java web for long time ... but from what i remember its was pure fun (plain jsp and servlets no frameworks ).

Comment: Resin has a PHP (called Quercus) implemented in Java so no buffer overruns :-)

Comment: why to use it ? if i use php i use php why i need all this?

Comment: At some point you might want to combine Java code and PHP in one application. Anyway, tomcat is a reference implementation that does not concern itself with performance and robustness while resin does.

Answer (score 0):

From development point of view always use an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans, makes the job easier n much faster. Here's a nice tutorial to get you started on developing web applications on Eclipse with Tomact integration - [WTP Tutorials](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html)